# Show image from one page to another page in javascript, without sending all div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make verification page that have a button verify, when click that button will be show image "Yes/tick" mark on other page. Verification rules : when meet the condition which is if have selected 3 checkbox, the verification is accepted, user will click button verify, and image yes mark will be showing in other page (the main page)

I've tried to send image to main page but just only showing image in current page and showing all div main page, not only image that I need. The checkbox rules already working with some show alert function

This is for the verification rules checkbox :

```
function check(){
    var checked=0;
    $( "input:checkbox" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            checked++;
        }
    });
    if(checked>2){
        alert('Ok!');
    }
    else{
        alert('At least 3 checkboxes need to be selected!');
    }
}
```

and the function for image that I'm trying :

```
function getImage(){
            localStorage.setItem('/biz/eKYC/EK01.html','../../sampleData/dummyImages/verifOK.jpeg');

        }


        var image = "../../sampleData/dummyImages/verifOK.jpeg";
        //location.href = '/biz/eKYC/EK01.html';
        //var page = '/biz/eKYC/EK01.html';

        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            $(".verif").click(function(){
                $(location).attr('href',image);
                $("#image").show();
                $("#custInfo").hide();
                return getImage()
            });
        }


        //          //              document.getElementById('imgVerifOK').src = icon.replace('30x30', '125x125');
        //          //              document.getElementById('imgVerifOK').style.display='block';
```

I expect just image that showing but it shows all div in main page

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell exactly what you're asking, or even what the intended code is supposed to accomplish, but in looking at your `toggle_visibility` function this line seems suspect:

```
$(location).attr('href',image)
```

This will change the URL of the page to be the URL of your verification image, and you do it whenever a user clicks on any element with the class `verif`. If that's actually what you intended you need to explain better about the structure of the DOM of your page (is every one of these images in an iframe?) and maybe show how things are going wrong.